# Is it possible to access a Facebook user's photo-gallery in Facebook Connect?

Tags: facebook

If the user "Connects" to your website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, for example, in PHP you would do:

```
try {
    $facebook_albums = $facebook->api_client->photos_getAlbums($facebook_user_id, null);
}catch (Exception $e) {

}
```

where $facebook_user_id is the user's facebook_uid (user id)

read more at http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Photos.getAlbums